# Expressjs redirect user to /logout with 401 error on API calls

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I have a use-case to redirect the user to login page when I get 401 error on API calls (AJAX calls). I have defined express middleware as following, to logout user and redirect to login page.

```
//logout route
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    passportConfig.reset(); //reset auth tokens
    res.redirect(config.uaaURL + '/logout?redirect=' + config.appURL);
});
```

I am using passportjs and connect-redis to store user token and client token in session and authenticate. User token is used for user session on the browser and client token is used for service calls. When user token expires I am able to redirect user to login page. Here is the challenge I am facing, I wrote a XMLHttpRequest intercepter as shown below to redirect the errors on Service calls (AJAX calls) to /logout route. I see it is making a /logout call but see Unauthorized in the page and after some time when I hit the same url it is redirecting me to the login page.

XMLHttpRequest interceptor snippet:

```
// Self contain and executed analymous function
(function() {
    var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    var setRequestHeader = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader;

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var oldOnReadyStateChange;

        function returnResponseToApp() {
            // continue to return data
            if (oldOnReadyStateChange) {
                oldOnReadyStateChange.call(self);
            }
        }

        // save old ready state change
        oldOnReadyStateChange = this.onreadystatechange;
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var response;

            if (self.readyState === 4 /* complete */) {
                // get x-csrf-token header

                if (self.status === 401 || self.status === 403) {
                    console.log('Resp status >>'+self.status);
                    /**
                     * when status is 403 access denied
                     * The app will redirect user to access denied page
                     */
                    if (self.status === 403) {
                        returnResponseToApp();
                    } else {
                        // when status is 401 not authenticated
                        try {
                            /**
                             * special case when user require to change password
                             * check the response description by converting response to JSON object
                             */
                            response = JSON.parse(self.response);
                            if (response.error_description === 'password_change_required') { // jshint ignore:line
                                returnResponseToApp();
                            } else {
                                // in all case when 401 is returned logout the user
                                this.redirectToLogout();
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            // in all case when 401 is returned logout the user
                            this.redirectToLogout();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    returnResponseToApp();
                }
            }
        };


        this.redirectToLogout = function() {
            window.location.replace('/logout');
            this.abort();
        }.bind(this);

        send.call(this, data);
    };
})();
```

The behaviour I see is:

[image]